# Acrobat dynamic stamp popup window to reflect stamp comment

Tags: javascript, popupwindow, acrobat, content-script

I am creating an application with an acrobat dynamic stamp pop up window and I would like it to reflect the stamp comment. My dynamic stamp has some JavaScript that will generate a pop-up window. The information on the pop-up window text field will become part of the stamp. I'm trying to add the contents of the pop-up window in two areas.

1. On the Dynamic stamp (done)
2. On the Stamp Comments (need help)

Below I added the JavaScript I currently have. If anyone here can help me find a solution, I'd really appreciate it.

[image]

```
var builder = 

{
        // These map to Text Fields in the Stamp
    textBoxes :
    [
        { field:"IsoNum", description:"Isometric Number:", default:function() { return Collab.user; } }     

    ]
}


/*********** belongs to: AcroForm:Calculation:Calculate ***********/

// SEE GLOBAL JAVASCRIPT SECTION FOR CUSTOMIZATION

if (event.source.forReal)
{
    var stampDialog = CreateDialog(builder);
    app.execDialog(stampDialog);    


    for (var i = 0; i < builder.textBoxes.length; ++i)
    {
        var t = builder.textBoxes[i];
        this.getField(t.field).value = stampDialog.textBoxResults[i];
    }
}

function CreateDialog(dialogBuilder)
{
    var sd = new Object();
    sd.builder = dialogBuilder;
    sd.textBoxResults = new Array();

    var optionsElements = new Array();  
    for (var i = 0; i < dialogBuilder.textBoxes.length; ++i)
    {
        var view = new Object();        
        view.type = "view";
        view.align_children = "align_row";
        view.elements = new Array();

        var t = dialogBuilder.textBoxes[i];

        var s = new Object();
        s.type = "static_text";
        s.item_id = "sta" + i;
        s.name = t.description;
        s.width = 110;

        var e = new Object();
        e.type = "edit_text";
        e.item_id = "edt" + i;
        e.width = 150;

        view.elements[0] = s;
        view.elements[1] = e;       

        optionsElements[i] = view;
    }

    var optionsCluster = 
    {
        type: "cluster",
        name: "Options",
        elements: optionsElements
    };

    sd.initialize = function(dialog)
    {
        var init = new Object();
        for (var i = 0; i < this.builder.textBoxes.length; ++i)
        {
            var t = this.builder.textBoxes[i];
            var id = "edt" + i;         
            init[id] = t.default();
        }

        dialog.load(init);
    };

    sd.commit = function(dialog)
    {
        var res = dialog.store();               

        for (var i = 0; i < this.builder.textBoxes.length; ++i)
        {
            var t = this.builder.textBoxes[i];
            var id = "edt" + i;
            this.textBoxResults[i] = res[id];           
        }
    };

    sd.description = 
    {
        name: "Stamp Dialog",
        elements:
        [
            {
                type: "view",
                align_children: "align_fill",
                elements:
                [
                    optionsCluster
                ]
            },
            {
                type: "ok"
            }
        ]
    };

    return sd;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any specific code but it seems you understand enough Acrobat JavaScript to understand my instructions.

The dialog code runs between the time you select and position the stamp and when the stamp actually gets created. For that reason, you can't set the contents of the note directly in your code because the stamp annotation doesn't actually exist until your commit function finishes. What you have to do instead is create a function that sets the contents of the note inside a timeOut and use a delay of about a half second.

Comment: thanks you for your comment, I actually don't know how to do what you suggested, will you be able to refer me to a source that has more information on this?